# Navigate a customer using Estimote indoor navigation IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, estimote, indoor-positioning-system

I have integrated Estimate indoor positioning system, but I am not able to route a user to particular location. Any help is appreciated.

```
#import "DirectMeViewController.h"
#import "ESTIndoorLocationManager.h"
#import "ESTLocationBuilder.h"
#import "ESTIndoorLocationView.h"
#import "ESTPositionView.h"
#import "ESTConfig.h"


@interface DirectMeViewController ()<ESTIndoorLocationManagerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) ESTIndoorLocationManager *manager;
@property (nonatomic, strong) ESTLocation *location;
@property (nonatomic, strong) ESTPositionView *positionView;
- (IBAction)closeBtnAction:(id)sender;

@end

@implementation DirectMeViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"location" ofType:@"json"];
    NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    // location.json file got from estimote indoor location app

    ESTLocation *location = [ESTLocationBuilder parseFromJSON:content];

    self.manager = [[ESTIndoorLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.manager.delegate = self;

    self.location = location;


}
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.locationView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    self.locationView.showTrace               = NO;
    self.locationView.rotateOnPositionUpdate  = NO;

    self.locationView.showWallLengthLabels    = YES;

    self.locationView.locationBorderColor     = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.locationView.locationBorderThickness = 6;
    self.locationView.doorColor               = [UIColor brownColor];
    self.locationView.doorThickness           = 5;
    self.locationView.traceColor              = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.locationView.traceThickness          = 2;
    self.locationView.wallLengthLabelsColor   = [UIColor yellowColor];


    [self.locationView drawLocation:self.location];


    // You can use positionView with set avatar to visualize accuracy circle.
    self.positionView = [[ESTPositionView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigation_guy"] location:self.location forViewWithBounds:self.locationView.bounds];
    self.positionView.hidden = YES;
    self.locationView.positionView = self.positionView;

    self.positionLabel.hidden = NO;


    self.locationView.positionImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navigation_guy.png"];

    [self.manager startIndoorLocation:self.location];

}
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.manager stopIndoorLocation];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)indoorLocationManager:(ESTIndoorLocationManager *)manager
            didUpdatePosition:(ESTOrientedPoint *)position
                 withAccuracy:(ESTPositionAccuracy)positionAccuracy
                   inLocation:(ESTLocation *)location
{
    self.positionLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"x: %.2f  y: %.2f   α: %.2f ",
                               position.x,
                               position.y,
                               position.orientation];
    [self.positionView updateAccuracy:positionAccuracy];
    [self.locationView updatePosition:position];
}

- (void)indoorLocationManager:(ESTIndoorLocationManager *)manager didFailToUpdatePositionWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    if (error.code == ESTIndoorPositionOutsideLocationError)
    {
        self.positionLabel.text = @"It seems you are not in this location.";
    }
    else if (error.code == ESTIndoorMagnetometerInitializationError)
    {
        self.positionLabel.text = @"It seems your magnetometer is not working.";
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
}
```

Above code shows how to trace users location using beacons. But I don't know how to route the user to a particular POI.

Comment: Your question is very generic. What have you done so far to implement the routing? What problems are you running into? Provide any relevant code examples if you think they'd help. You can read more about asking good questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Well-written questions will ensure you get answers faster.